# 100% classifier accuracy after using train_test_split

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

I'm working on the mushroom classification data set (found here: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/mushroom-classification).

I'm trying to split my data into training and testing sets for my models, however if i use the train_test_split method my models always achieve 100% accuracy. This is not the case when i split my data manually.

```
x = data.copy()
y = x['class']
del x['class']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)

model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(x_test)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
```

This produces:

```
[[1299    0]
 [   0 1382]]
1.0
```

If I split the data manually I get a more reasonable result.

```
x = data.copy()
y = x['class']
del x['class']

x_train = x[0:5443]
x_test = x[5444:]
y_train = y[0:5443]
y_test = y[5444:]

model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(x_test)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
```

Result:

```
[[2007    0]
 [ 336  337]]
0.8746268656716418
```

What could be causing this behaviour?

**Edit:**
As per request I'm including shapes of slices.

train_test_split:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
```

Result:

```
(5443, 64)
(5443,)
(2681, 64)
(2681,)
```

Manual split:

```
x_train = x[0:5443]
x_test = x[5444:]
y_train = y[0:5443]
y_test = y[5444:]

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
```

Result:

```
(5443, 64)
(5443,)
(2680, 64)
(2680,)
```

I've tried defining my own split function and the resulting split also results in 100% classifier accuracy.

Here's the code for the split

```
def split_data(dataFrame, testRatio):
  dataCopy = dataFrame.copy()
  testCount = int(len(dataFrame)*testRatio)
  dataCopy = dataCopy.sample(frac = 1)
  y = dataCopy['class']
  del dataCopy['class']
  return dataCopy[testCount:], dataCopy[0:testCount], y[testCount:], y[0:testCount]
```

Comment: What are the shapes of `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` after splitting with each method?

Comment: @G.Anderson I've updated my question with the shapes

Comment: Does the behavior persist if you run the train_test_plit again, or if you change the `test_size` parameter? It's possible (though very unlikely) that you got an insanely lucky split the first time around. Otherwise, are there any other transformations you did to your data that aren't shown? This looks a lot like data leakage between train and test, or between targets and features

Comment: It persists throughout the tries and if I change the test size (whatever I change it to the accuracy is 100%).
I've done some pre-processing on the data but it's all done before I split the dataset.

Comment: Wait! What `preprocessing` have you done before split? You should not do `feature selection` on the whole data set. Just on train set and transform train, test set with that. Also same for `standard scalar` fit the training data after split and transform both train, test with that. Likely you are leaking data from train to test set that way if there is no problem with your manual split code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got lucky there on your train_test_split.
The split you are doing manually may be having the most unseen data, which is doing better validation than the train_test_split which internally shuffled the data to split it.

For better validation use K-fold cross validation, which will allow to verify the model accuracy with each of the different parts in your data as your test and rest part as train.

Answer (score 1):

Your manual train test split does not have shuffle but scikit function has shuffle on by default. Split shapes are same but data is different.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = np.arange(18).reshape((9, 2)), range(9)
print(X)
print(list(y))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

print("\nTraining with shuffle:")
print(X_train)
print(y_train)


print("\nTesting with shuffle:")
print(X_test)
print(y_test)


print("\nWithout Shuffle:")
tmp = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, shuffle=False)
print(tmp[0])
print(tmp[2])
print()
print(tmp[1])
print(tmp[3])
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 4  5]
 [ 6  7]
 [ 8  9]
 [10 11]
 [12 13]
 [14 15]
 [16 17]]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Training with shuffle:
[[ 0  1]
 [16 17]
 [ 4  5]
 [ 8  9]
 [ 6  7]
 [12 13]]
[0, 8, 2, 4, 3, 6]

Testing with shuffle:
[[14 15]
 [ 2  3]
 [10 11]]
[7, 1, 5]

Without Shuffle:
[[ 0  1]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 4  5]
 [ 6  7]
 [ 8  9]
 [10 11]]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[[12 13]
 [14 15]
 [16 17]]
[6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: I understand that part, but why would it affect the outcome of the classifier?

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. Have you confirmed that this will affect the behavior of a model as described in the OP?

Comment: Setting shuffle to false does affect the accuracy of the model.

Comment: It seems like no matter what I do, if I shuffle the order of the data I get 100% accuracy.

Comment: I just checked UCI repo, it says, edible: 4208 (51.8%), poisonous: 3916 (48.2%), with 33% split without shuffle dataset is imbalanced. 8124 * 0.33 = 2681 test and 8124 - 2681 = 5443 training. If the dataset is not organized serially first edible then poisons then 5443 - 4208 =  1235 for poisonous and 4208 for edible. This is imbalanced.

Comment: @DonAndre Can you check with stratified k fold, balanced accuracy or other metrics and roc. Also what is the result with another not so powerful classifier as xgb with above. https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Mushroom

Comment: You can check this, https://www.kaggle.com/usharengaraju/mushroom-classification-using-randomforest

Comment: @B200011011 I've used XGB, MLP, LinearSVC and a Decision Tree to test the data. Whenver I shuffle all of the models I used have 100% accuracy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206749/discussion-between-don-andre-and-b200011011).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the results were correct, I was just going the wrong way about testing the results produced by the model.

I've opened another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939691/100-classifier-accuracy-when-shuffling-data-rows) where someone suggested to try cross validation which seemed to do the trick.