# 100% classifier accuracy when shuffling data rows

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I'm working on the mushroom classification data set (found here :https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/mushroom-classification)

I've done some pre-processing on the data (removed redundant attributes, changed categorical data to numerical) and I'm trying to use my data to train classifiers.

Whenever I shuffle my data, either manually or by using train_test_split, all of the models which I use (XGB, MLP, LinearSVC, Decision Tree) have 100% accuracy. Whenever I test the models on unshuffled data the accuracy is around 50-85%.

Here are my methods for splitting the data:

```
x = testing.copy()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True)
```

and manually

```
x = testing.copy()
x = x.sample(frac=1)

testRatio = 0.3
testCount = int(len(x)*testRatio)

x_train = x[testCount:]
x_test = x[0:testCount]
y_train = y[testCount:]
y_test = y[0:testCount]
```

Is there something I'm doing completely wrong and missing?

**Edit:**
The only difference that I can see when splitting data with and without shuffling the rows is the distribution of the classes.

Without shuffling:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)

print(y_test.value_counts())
print(y_train.value_counts())
```

Results in:

```
0    1828
1     610
Name: class, dtype: int64
1    3598
0    2088
Name: class, dtype: int64
```

While shuffling:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True)

print(y_test.value_counts())
print(y_train.value_counts())
```

Results in:

```
0    1238
1    1200
Name: class, dtype: int64
1    3008
0    2678
Name: class, dtype: int64
```

I don't see how this would affect the model's accuracy in such a big way though.

**Edit2:**
Following PV8's advice I've tried verifying my results by using cross validation and it seems to do the trick, I'm getting much more reasonable results this way.

```
model = LinearSVC()
scores = cross_val_score(model,x,y,cv=5)
print(scores)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
```

Output:

```
[1.         1.         1.         1.         0.75246305]
Accuracy: 0.95 (+/- 0.20)
```

Comment: Did you try using `train_test_split` with `shuffle=False`? If that also returns good accuracy then it means something is wrong with your way of manually splitting. Try printing all data with their corresponding shapes and compare.

Comment: @Sharan train_test_split with shuffle=False results in the model's accuracy being more reasonable (around 80%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be normal behavior, how many shuffles did you try?

This is indicating that your data is quite fluaktiv to the way you split it. I hope you measured the test accuracy and not the train one?

I would suggest you to use [cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), this will help you to verify your general results.

Comment: I've tried many shuffles over 2 days now and yes I checked the test accuracy. I will try cross validation later today and will update the question with my findings.

Comment: Your advice turned out to do the trick, I've updated my question with the results.